# Best practices for "Semi-temporary" tables

Tags: sql, database-performance, temp-tables

I'm making a multiplayer game (turn-based) app that will need to trade match data between users during the match. After the match, the Round data will be useless.

What are some best practices for handling these types of scenarios.

I thought of:

- Creating tables that exist for the duration of the match which will have the naming convention of "Round" + MatchID. So there would be 1 table for each instantiated match. At the end of a match, this table will be dropped.
- Having only 1 Round table and at the conclusion of a match, delete all rows where MatchId = completed Match.

I'm not sure which approach is the best performance-wise. Is there any guidance on this topic? Also, I'm not sure what scenario 1 would be called. I know the terms "temporary" and "transient" are reserved for other use cases.

Comment: Having a dynamic database design is unusual and should be avoided. Use one table.

Comment: You can add a column for the match id and do a cleanup when the match is finished.

Answer (score 0):

In general, such temporary tables are probably not the best idea.

The better solution is to have a single table for *all matches*.  You can insert rows into the tables, modify them, and so on using the key for the particular match.

Having the history of what happens during a match can be quite convenient.  However, if you want to delete the rows for a given match, you can do so when the match ends or at some other convenient time.